# Reflecting Icon Fonts with CSS

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome

I'm working on a personal project (will be using a webkit based browser), I want to use a font like font awsesome for my icons, so I can change the color with theme changes, scale them, etc.

Is there a way to do reflections without converting them to images. (I *could* live with that, as long as I was still able to change the color - for example, if I convert to an images as black text and then change to a theme that uses blue text, I want to be able to change the color with LESS/CSS).

Attached is an example

Thanks

Mark

[image: Examples]

Comment: You can do that with CSS3. For example, use ::after to insert another version of the icon below the main one, then flip it 180 degrees and do a gradient overlay that fades to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it (for webkit, which is all I need for this project: will redo once there's wider support element())

JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dHBLT/2/

HTML:

```
<svg display="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="560" height="32" viewBox="0 0 560 32">
    <defs>
        <g id="icon-home">
            <path class="path1" d="M32 18.451l-16-12.42-16 12.42v-5.064l16-12.42 16 12.42zM28 18v12h-8v-8h-8v8h-8v-12l12-9z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="icon-music">
            <path class="path1" d="M10 6l22-6v23c0 2.761-3.134 5-7 5s-7-2.239-7-5c0-2.761 3.134-5 7-5 1.074 0 2.091 0.173 3 0.481v-10.3l-14 3.818v15c0 2.761-3.134 5-7 5-3.866 0-7-2.239-7-5 0-2.761 3.134-5 7-5 1.074 0 2.091 0.173 3 0.481v-16.481z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="icon-headphones">
            <path class="path1" d="M6 18.071v13.857c0.327 0.047 0.66 0.071 1 0.071h1v-14h-1c-0.34 0-0.673 0.025-1 0.071zM24 18v14h1c0.34 0 0.673-0.025 1-0.071v-13.857c-0.327-0.047-0.66-0.071-1-0.071h-1zM32 16c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16s-16 7.163-16 16c0 1.919 0.338 3.76 0.958 5.465-0.609 1.038-0.958 2.245-0.958 3.535 0 2.792 1.635 5.202 4 6.326v-12.652c-0.629 0.299-1.206 0.689-1.714 1.153-0.187-0.913-0.286-1.859-0.286-2.827 0-7.732 6.268-14 14-14s14 6.268 14 14c0 0.969-0.098 1.914-0.286 2.827-0.509-0.464-1.085-0.854-1.714-1.153v12.652c2.365-1.124 4-3.534 4-6.326 0-1.29-0.349-2.498-0.958-3.535 0.62-1.705 0.958-3.546 0.958-5.465z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="icon-film">
            <path class="path1" d="M0 4v24h32v-24h-32zM6 26h-4v-4h4v4zM6 18h-4v-4h4v4zM6 10h-4v-4h4v4zM24 26h-16v-20h16v20zM30 26h-4v-4h4v4zM30 18h-4v-4h4v4zM30 10h-4v-4h4v4zM12 10v12l8-6z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="icon-camera">
            <path class="path1" d="M12 9c0-2.761 2.239-5 5-5s5 2.239 5 5c0 2.761-2.239 5-5 5-2.761 0-5-2.239-5-5zM0 9c0-2.761 2.239-5 5-5s5 2.239 5 5c0 2.761-2.239 5-5 5-2.761 0-5-2.239-5-5zM24 19v-3c0-1.1-0.9-2-2-2h-20c-1.1 0-2 0.9-2 2v10c0 1.1 0.9 2 2 2h20c1.1 0 2-0.9 2-2v-3l8 5v-14l-8 5zM20 24h-16v-6h16v6z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="icon-busy">
            <path class="path1" d="M22.781 16c4.305-2.729 7.219-7.975 7.219-14 0-0.677-0.037-1.345-0.109-2h-27.783c-0.072 0.655-0.109 1.323-0.109 2 0 6.025 2.914 11.271 7.219 14-4.305 2.729-7.219 7.975-7.219 14 0 0.677 0.037 1.345 0.109 2h27.783c0.072-0.655 0.109-1.323 0.109-2 0-6.025-2.914-11.271-7.219-14zM5 30c0-5.841 2.505-10.794 7-12.428v-3.143c-4.495-1.634-7-6.587-7-12.428v0h22c0 5.841-2.505 10.794-7 12.428v3.143c4.495 1.634 7 6.587 7 12.428h-22zM19.363 20.925c-2.239-1.27-2.363-2.918-2.363-3.918v-2.007c0-1 0.119-2.654 2.367-3.927 1.203-0.699 2.244-1.761 3.033-3.073h-12.799c0.79 1.313 1.832 2.376 3.036 3.075 2.239 1.27 2.363 2.918 2.363 3.918v2.007c0 1-0.119 2.654-2.367 3.927-2.269 1.318-3.961 3.928-4.472 7.073h15.677c-0.511-3.147-2.204-5.758-4.475-7.075z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="icon-key">
            <path class="path1" d="M22 0c-5.523 0-10 4.477-10 10 0 0.626 0.058 1.238 0.168 1.832l-12.168 12.168v6c0 1.105 0.895 2 2 2h2v-2h4v-4h4v-4h4l2.595-2.595c1.063 0.385 2.209 0.595 3.405 0.595 5.523 0 10-4.477 10-10s-4.477-10-10-10zM24.996 10.004c-1.657 0-3-1.343-3-3s1.343-3 3-3 3 1.343 3 3-1.343 3-3 3z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="icon-cog">
            <path class="path1" d="M29.181 19.070c-1.679-2.908-0.669-6.634 2.255-8.328l-3.145-5.447c-0.898 0.527-1.943 0.829-3.058 0.829-3.361 0-6.085-2.742-6.085-6.125h-6.289c0.008 1.044-0.252 2.103-0.811 3.070-1.679 2.908-5.411 3.897-8.339 2.211l-3.144 5.447c0.905 0.515 1.689 1.268 2.246 2.234 1.676 2.903 0.672 6.623-2.241 8.319l3.145 5.447c0.895-0.522 1.935-0.82 3.044-0.82 3.35 0 6.067 2.725 6.084 6.092h6.289c-0.003-1.034 0.259-2.080 0.811-3.038 1.676-2.903 5.399-3.894 8.325-2.219l3.145-5.447c-0.899-0.515-1.678-1.266-2.232-2.226zM16 22.479c-3.578 0-6.479-2.901-6.479-6.479 0-3.578 2.901-6.479 6.479-6.479 3.578 0 6.479 2.901 6.479 6.479-0 3.578-2.901 6.479-6.479 6.479z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="icon-glass">
            <path class="path1" d="M19 12c-1 1-1 1-1 2v14h4c1.105 0 2 0.895 2 2h-16c0-1.105 0.895-2 2-2h4v-14c0-1 0-1-1-2l-8.586-8.586c-0.778-0.778-0.514-1.414 0.586-1.414h22c1.1 0 1.364 0.636 0.586 1.414l-8.585 8.585c-0 0-0 0-0 0z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="icon-mug">
            <path class="path1" d="M26 10h-2v-3c0-2.761-5.373-5-12-5-6.627 0-12 2.239-12 5v18c0 2.761 5.373 5 12 5s12-2.239 12-5v-3h2c3.3 0 6-2.7 6-6s-2.7-6-6-6zM5.502 5.925c1.811-0.597 4.118-0.925 6.498-0.925s4.688 0.329 6.498 0.925c1.156 0.381 1.857 0.789 2.232 1.075-0.375 0.286-1.076 0.694-2.232 1.075-1.811 0.597-4.118 0.925-6.498 0.925s-4.688-0.329-6.498-0.925c-1.156-0.381-1.857-0.789-2.232-1.075 0.375-0.286 1.075-0.694 2.232-1.075zM28.261 17.761c-0.276 0.276-0.872 0.739-1.761 0.739h-2.5v-5h2.5c0.89 0 1.486 0.463 1.761 0.739s0.739 0.871 0.739 1.761-0.463 1.486-0.739 1.761z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="icon-food">
            <path class="path1" d="M27 0c-2.762 0-5 2.239-5 5v15h4v12h6v-27c0-2.761-2.239-5-5-5zM13 0c-0.552 0-1 0.448-1 1v7c0 0.276-0.448 0.5-1 0.5-0.552 0-1-0.224-1-0.5v-7c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1-0.552 0-1 0.448-1 1v7c0 0.276-0.448 0.5-1 0.5-0.552 0-1-0.224-1-0.5v-7c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1-0.552 0-1 0.448-1 1v7c0 0.276-0.448 0.5-1 0.5s-1-0.224-1-0.5v-7c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1s-1 0.448-1 1v9c0 0.885 0.783 1.378 1.656 2 1.1 0.783 2.344 1.77 2.344 4v16h6v-16c0-2.23 1.243-3.217 2.344-4 0.873-0.622 1.656-1.115 1.656-2v-9c0-0.552-0.448-1-1-1z"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="icon-tree">
            <path class="path1" d="M30.5 24h-0.5v-6.5c0-1.93-1.57-3.5-3.5-3.5h-8.5v-4h0.5c0.825 0 1.5-0.675 1.5-1.5v-5c0-0.825-0.675-1.5-1.5-1.5h-5c-0.825 0-1.5 0.675-1.5 1.5v5c0 0.825 0.675 1.5 1.5 1.5h0.5v4h-8.5c-1.93 0-3.5 1.57-3.5 3.5v6.5h-0.5c-0.825 0-1.5 0.675-1.5 1.5v5c0 0.825 0.675 1.5 1.5 1.5h5c0.825 0 1.5-0.675 1.5-1.5v-5c0-0.825-0.675-1.5-1.5-1.5h-0.5v-6h8v6h-0.5c-0.825 0-1.5 0.675-1.5 1.5v5c0 0.825 0.675 1.5 1.5 1.5h5c0.825 0 1.5-0.675 1.5-1.5v-5c0-0.825-0.675-1.5-1.5-1.5h-0.5v-6h8v6h-0.5c-0.825 0-1.5 0.675-1.5 1.5v5c0 0.825 0.675 1.5 1.5 1.5h5c0.825 0 1.5-0.675 1.5-1.5v-5c0-0.825-0.675-1.5-1.5-1.5zM6 30h-4v-4h4v4zM18 30h-4v-4h4v4zM14 8v-4h4v4h-4zM30 30h-4v-4h4v4z"></path>
        </g>
    </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="icon red" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-home"></use></svg>
<svg class="icon green" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-camera"></use></svg>
<svg class="icon blue" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-music"></use></svg>
<svg class="icon " viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-key"></use></svg>
<svg class="icon " viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="#icon-cog"></use></svg>
```

CSS

```
 .icon {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    fill: #333;
}

.red {fill: #F00;}
.green {fill: #0F0;}
.blue {fill: #00F;}


         svg{           
            -webkit-box-reflect: below 1px
            -webkit-gradient(linear,
                            center top,
                            center bottom,
                            from(transparent),
                            color-stop(0,transparent),
                            to(rgba(255,255,255,0.5)));
                              text-align: center;

                              margin-bottom: 64px;

        }
```

Hope this helps someone

Regards

mark

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://www.google.com/fonts and select a font from them add to your collection and add the href link that google gives back to an html page you made. You can use CSS to customized the text color and size you want.

html

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Changa+One|Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

}

Comment: Thanks for reply. I couldn't find an easy way to do the reflections with fade) on fonts. SVG works great from me: Can scale, Can color, Can reflect